# How can i get a view with 2 seperate colors unlike a gradient in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface, styling

I Have a UI to design in react native which looks like in the image below, you can ignore the UI components I am facing only an issue with the background view which has 2 colors.

I tried using another inside the parent view with an absolute position and giving it bottom: 0, and some height: 100, zIndex: 1, but this doesnt seem to work.

```
<View style={{flex:1}}
      >
        {
          ......
        } // All my other UI components
        <View
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            bottom: 0,
            height: 100,
            backgroundColor: "white",
            zIndex: 1
          }}
        />
</View>
```

https://i.ibb.co/XWVM5mS/Untitled.png

I just want to learn how to get two-tone background colors in the View component with other child components overlaying on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `left` and `right` too

```js
<View
  style={{
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    zIndex: 1
  }}
/>
```